# Bluemix Docker container cf ic run doesn't seem to accept -p sub-command

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

The https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_native-docker.html says `cf ic run` support `-p` sub-command.

However, I have attempted many time to bind port with

```
cf ic run -it --name container_name -p 80:8080 registry.../ns/image_name:tag
```

However, port 80 is not binded but the default port which exposed by the docker which in this case 8080.

Is this a bug, or I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the command in the wrong way. Please take a look at the [cf ic run Documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__run). As you can see the syntax is:

```
cf ic run -p <hostPort>:<containerPort> registry.../ns/image_name:tag
```

That means that if you want to bind the port 80 on the container to the port 8080 on the host you should do this:

```
cf ic run -p 8080:80 registry.../ns/image_name:tag
```

The behavior that you are experiencing is correct: you are actually binding the port 8080 on the container to the 80 on the host, so it is correct that you see the 8080 open on your container.

Comment: I have noticed the same problem. I start container with `cf ic run -p <ip>:80:8080 registry/ns/image:tag` and then in the output of `cf ic ps` I see that the exposed port is `<ip>:8080->8080/tcp`, that is host port is the same as container, even if I provided different ones. Also the documentation page you linked to mentions optional un-named argument `[IP_address]` which the current `cf ic run` command does not accept. Is this outdated documentation?

Comment: It should be the last version of the docs, what error do you get? Did you install the latest cf and cf ic version?

Comment: If I run `cf ic run <ip>:80:8080 registry/ns/image:tag`, I get `Error response from daemon: "Image not found"`. It really looks like a typo in documentation. I have installed `cf` and `ic` today and their versions are `6.13.0-e68ce0f-2015-10-15T22:53:58+00:00` and `0.8.788` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

your run command creates a mapping between 8080 port on your container and the 80 on hosting env: if your container exposes the 8080 port I think it should be still reachable on the containers env